# JPA SPECIFICATION WITH INTERFACE PROJECTIONS

Tags: jpa, projection, predicate, specifications

I have problems that how to implement jpa specification with parameters and dynamic where whose response should be a list of interface projections containing some columns of 3 related entities, because findAll generated error because the specification is about an entity and I hope a list of interface projection like answer, indicate clash

I need an example how implement it